# How do I check my sp_Blitz/sp_WhoIsActive versions across multiple servers/databases?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-blitz, multi-server-admin

I have a bunch of SQL Servers registered within my SSMS, lots of different SQL versions, editions and DB compatibilities.

I want to check out if **any** of those servers have **any** of the [sp_Blitz](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit) or [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com) stored procedures installed, and which versions they are.

I know I can **right-click** on my **Registered Servers group** and open **one** query window that connects to **all** the servers in the group, but is there a reliable way to check which SProcs and versions I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get quite a usable list by sniffing out the versions within the SProcs' source code,
as stored within the `sys.comments` tables.

[image: screenshot of T-SQL results]

A healthy amount of assumptions was made,
so **test this code on a solitary test instance first**,
before going wild on your multitude of Production servers...

**Edit**: added Adam Machanic's [sp_WhoIsActive](http://WhoIsActive.com) as an example of how to add to this scanner script.

```
USE [master];

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##DBA_SProcs') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##DBA_SProcs;

CREATE TABLE ##DBA_SProcs (
     DBName             NVARCHAR(100) NULL
    ,SProcName          NVARCHAR (50) NULL
    ,VersionString      NVARCHAR (50) NULL
    ,VersionDateString  NVARCHAR (50) NULL
    );

EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb
     @replacechar = N'¬'
    ,@command1 = N'
USE[¬];

INSERT INTO ##DBA_SProcs
SELECT
     DB_NAME() AS DBName
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            SUBSTRING([text], CHARINDEX(''sp_Blitz'', [text], 1), 18)
            ,'']'','''')
            ,''('','''')
            ,CHAR(9)/*Tab*/,'' '')
            ,CHAR(10)/*LF*/,'' '')
            ,CHAR(13)/*CR*/,'' '')
            ,''@He'','''')
            ,''@Ch'','''')
        )) AS SProcName
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING([text], CHARINDEX(''T @Version'', [text], 1) + 3, 15)
        ,'', @'' , '''')
        ,''Version = '' , '''')
        AS VersionString
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(
        CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('', @VersionD'', [text], 1) > 0
        THEN SUBSTRING([text], CHARINDEX('', @VersionD'', [text], 1) + 3, 24)
        ELSE SUBSTRING([text], CHARINDEX(''T @VersionD'', [text], 1) + 3, 24)
        END
        ,''VersionDate = '' , '''')
        ,'''''''' , '''')
        AS VersionDateString
FROM sys.syscomments sc
WHERE sc.colid <= 1
  AND sc.[text] LIKE ''%sp_Blitz%''
  AND sc.[text] LIKE ''%T @Version%'';

INSERT INTO ##DBA_SProcs
SELECT
     DB_NAME() AS DBName
    ,''sp_WhoIsActive'' AS SProcName
    ,SUBSTRING(
        [text]
        ,CHARINDEX(''Who Is Active? v'', [text], 1) + 15
        ,7
        ) AS VersionString
    ,REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING([text], CHARINDEX(''Who Is Active? v'', [text], 1) + 23, 10)
        ,''-'' , '''')
        AS VersionDateString
FROM sys.syscomments sc
WHERE sc.[text] LIKE ''%sp_WhoIsActive%''
  AND sc.[text] LIKE ''%Who Is Active? v%'';
';

SELECT *
FROM ##DBA_SProcs
ORDER BY DBName, SProcName;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##DBA_SProcs') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##DBA_SProcs;
```

Answer (score 4):

For sp_Blitz, there's an [enhancement request filed at Github to add outputs for version](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/1237), and if you'd like to influence how the work is done (or contribute code), you're welcome to leave comments over there.

For sp_WhoIsActive, the author Adam Machanic is [considering adding an output to the Messages tab](https://twitter.com/BrentO/status/963103273967345664) each time it runs.

Until then, Oreo's suggestion above of checking the code is the best one. We won't break that intentionally - we haven't changed those strings in years, and don't intend to start, heh.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running something like this:

```
create table #tmp (line varchar(max))

insert into #tmp
exec sp_helptext 'sp_Blitz'

declare @version varchar(50);

select @version = Left(line, CHARINDEX('''',line,CHARINDEX('''',line,1)+1))
from #tmp
where line like '%@Version =%'

set @version = reverse(left(REVERSE(@version),CHARINDEX('''',reverse(@version),2)))

select replace(@version,'''','')

drop table #tmp
```